# Razor is not writing my "selected" value into the page

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have setup the following loop, which correctly populates a select control:

```
<select name="apisel" id="apisel" onchange="SelectedIndexChanged">
    @foreach (var item in Model.APIs)
    {

        <option value="@item.ApiID" @item.SelectedString>
            @item.ApiTitle
        </option>
    }
</select>
```

I am trying to use `@item.SelectedString` to add the string "selected" into the page for the selected combo box item.

However, this is not working.  So as a test, I just forced that string to always be "test", however, the page generates the HTML without the `@item.SelectedString` ever showing up!  In addition, the space before `@item.SelectedString` is also not there.

Does anyone know why this is?  Is Razor trying to do something "smart" here?

Comment: Have you tried setting it to something that would be proper HTML? As in a key/value pair

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen adding the keyword selected there is valid - it indicates that item is selected

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The new Tag Helpers are overriding your attempts.

You can manually [opt-out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1#opting-out-of-individual-elements) for the `<option>` elements with `!`

```
<select name="apisel" id="apisel" onchange="SelectedIndexChanged">
    @foreach (var item in Model.APIs)
    {
        <!option value="@item.ApiID" @item.SelectedString>
            @item.ApiTitle
        </!option>
    }
</select><br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 14):

You generally cannot output arbitrary strings within HTML tags. The HTML is actually parsed by Razor for its tag helpers feature, so it needs to be well-formed. If you try to do that, you will just get the following error:

> error RZ1031: The tag helper 'option' must not have C# in the element's attribute declaration area.

You can disable the tag helper parsing there by adding a `!` in front of the tag name:

```
<!option value="@item.ApiID" @item.SelectedString>@item.ApiTitle</!option>
```

A much better option however would be to simply *use* the tag helper to select the option: You don’t actually need to construct a `SelectedString` that just contains `"selected"`. Instead, you can just *set* the `selected` attribute of the element (or rather the tag helper) to a boolean:

```
<option value="@item.ApiID" selected="@item.IsSelected">@item.ApiTitle</option>
```

This will properly set the `selected` attribute when `item.IsSelected` is true, or omit the attribute completely when it is false.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it solves OP's answer while using the newer Razor code method.

Answer (score 1):

How I solved my version of this problem:

```
<select name="apisel" id="apisel" onchange="SelectedIndexChanged">
@foreach (var item in Model.APIs)
{
    @if (item.isSelected)
    {
    <option value="@item.ApiID" selected="selected">
        @item.ApiTitle
    </option>
    }
    else
    {
    <option value="@item.ApiID">
        @item.ApiTitle
    </option>
   }
}
```

Seemed a bit cleaner than using the ! version