# Errors and warnings using @functions block in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, razor-pages

Because the `@helper` directive is no longer supported in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, I've been using the `@functions` directive instead.

```
@functions
{
    void RenderTask(Models.Task task)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="@Model.CssClass">
                <p class="compact">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">@task.Title</span>
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(task.Description))
                    {
                        <br />@task.Description
                    }
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="@Model.CssClass">
                <img src="~/images/Edit.png" class="edit-area button-img" data-id="@task.Id" title="Edit" />
                <img src="~/images/Delete.png" class="delete-area button-img" data-id="@task.Id" title="Delete" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

This seems to work but I get an error:

> Error MVC1006: The method contains a TagHelper and therefore must be async and return a Task. For instance, usage of ~/ typically results in a TagHelper and requires an async Task returning parent method.

So I changed this function to be `async`, and I used the `await` keyword any place it is called.

```
@functions
{
    async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RenderTask(Models.Task task)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="@Model.CssClass">
                <p class="compact">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">@task.Title</span>
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(task.Description))
                    {
                        <br />@task.Description
                    }
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="@Model.CssClass">
                <img src="~/images/Edit.png" class="edit-area button-img" data-id="@task.Id" title="Edit" />
                <img src="~/images/Delete.png" class="delete-area button-img" data-id="@task.Id" title="Delete" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

This actually works but I get warnings:

> ...\Razor\Pages\Tasks\Index.cshtml.g.cs(286,200,286,202): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
>   ...\Razor\Pages\Tasks\Index.cshtml.g.cs(312,200,312,202): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

*Index.cshtml.g.cs* appears to be some sort of intermediary file. But I don't know what the numbers are that follow it, and double clicking these warnings does not take me to the offending line.

At this point, I'm not sure what the problem is. I've Googled extensively but haven't found a good example of this that shows what I'm supposed to be doing. Any suggestions appreciated.

**Update:**

Here's a section of *Index.cshtml.g.cs*:

```
#nullable restore
#line 86 "D:\Users\Jonathan\source\repos\Bamtok\Bamtok\Pages\Tasks\Index.cshtml"
                                                                          Write(task.Id);

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
        __tagHelperStringValueBuffer = EndWriteTagHelperAttribute();
        __tagHelperExecutionContext.AddHtmlAttribute("data-id", Html.Raw(__tagHelperStringValueBuffer), global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        __tagHelperExecutionContext.AddHtmlAttribute(__tagHelperAttribute_3);
        await __tagHelperRunner.RunAsync(__tagHelperExecutionContext); // *** ERROR HERE! ***
        if (!__tagHelperExecutionContext.Output.IsContentModified)
        {
            await __tagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync();
        }
        Write(__tagHelperExecutionContext.Output);
        __tagHelperExecutionContext = __tagHelperScopeManager.End();
        WriteLiteral("\r\n                ");
        __tagHelperExecutionContext = __tagHelperScopeManager.Begin("img", global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagMode.SelfClosing, "5fc6845fce9caf31066e5edd3fc6a51f323364e715810", async() => {
        }
        );
```

Comment: Note that there are also cases where standard HTML elements like `option` are triggering TagHelpers and causing the error.  See here for a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689389/746984

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft [has just confirmed](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20055) the warnings are a bug.

Answer (score 5):

```
@functions 
{
    public async Task RenderItem(string date,string time,string id)
    {
        <td>@date</td>
        <td>@time</td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" class="form-inline" asp-page-handler="view" asp-route-id="@id">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">@id</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    }
}

Usage

 <tr>@{await RenderItem(@date.ToShortDateString(), time, id);}</tr>
```

Comment: As a general advice: Usually it is better if you add the errors and/or warning you get in your questions.

Answer (score 3):

There's at least 4 workarounds:

#### Solution 1: Return `Task` but don't be `async`:

You can safely ignore the compiler saying it must be an async function because all the compiler cares about is that the function returns `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`. So you can return a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` without using `await` though it means you'll need a superfluous `return Task.CompletedTask;` in it somewhere:

```
@functions
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task RenderTask( Models.Task task )
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="@Model.CssClass">
                <p class="compact">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">@task.Title</span>
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(task.Description))
                    {
                        <br />@task.Description
                    }
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="@Model.CssClass">
                <img src="~/images/Edit.png" class="edit-area button-img" data-id="@task.Id" title="Edit" />
                <img src="~/images/Delete.png" class="delete-area button-img" data-id="@task.Id" title="Delete" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

### Solution 2: Alternatively, use a wrapper:

```
@functions
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task ShutUpRazor<T>( Action<T> renderFunc, T arg )
    {
        renderFunc( arg );
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    void RenderTask( Models.Task task )
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="@Model.CssClass">
                <p class="compact">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">@task.Title</span>
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(task.Description))
                    {
                        <br />@task.Description
                    }
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="@Model.CssClass">
                <img src="~/images/Edit.png" class="edit-area button-img" data-id="@task.Id" title="Edit" />
                <img src="~/images/Delete.png" class="delete-area button-img" data-id="@task.Id" title="Delete" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<section>
    @( this.ShutUpRazor( this.RenderTask, this.Model.MyTask ); )
</section>
```

#### Solution 3: Suppress the warnings:

```
@functions
{
    #pragma warning disable 1998
    void RenderTask( etc )
    {
        etc
    }
    #pragma warning restore 1998
}
```

#### Solution 4: Use `async` functions and `await` only a `Yield`:

```
@functions
{
    async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RenderTask( Models.Task task )
    {
        await Task.Yield();

        <tr>
            <td class="@Model.CssClass">
                <p class="compact">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">@task.Title</span>
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(task.Description))
                    {
                        <br />@task.Description
                    }
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="@Model.CssClass">
                <img src="~/images/Edit.png" class="edit-area button-img" data-id="@task.Id" title="Edit" />
                <img src="~/images/Delete.png" class="delete-area button-img" data-id="@task.Id" title="Delete" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: *Solution 1* gives me several warnings and errors. : *Error CS4032: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<Task>'.*.

Comment: Also, where I call it without `await`, I get the warning *Warning CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.*.

Comment: @JonathanWood The error is interesting - can you find the Razor-compiler generated *.cs file (usually in your PC’s “Temporary ASP.NET Files” folder or your project’s “Obj” folder) and add it to your Question post - I’d like to see it.

Comment: The file is large but I added several lines to my question. (Comments indicate the location of the error.)

Comment: @JonathanWood Ah, I see the problem now. I forgot about all the _unnecessary_ `async`/`await` stuff that Razor adds now (I hope they fix it in the next release). Unfortunately like you **have** to use `async Task<>` - but you can safely add `#pragma warning disable...` to suppress the warning about using `async` without `await` (because the `await` is being added by Razor when it compiles your code into the `...g.cs` file).

Comment: Okay, well I have no idea why I have to jump through hoops on this. `@helpers` used to work just fine. Anyway, I've [reported this to Microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20055). Have to see if they have anything to say about this.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround of the current Razor bug best working for me is to make the function `async` and call it with `await` in razor code scope. Example:

```
async Task RenderName (string name)
{
    <a asp-action="TagHelperForcesAsync">dear @name</a>
}
```

Used

```
<p>Hello @{await RenderName("John");}</p>
```